# How to make a relation in Entity Framework with foreign keys that point to primary keys with a different number of properties as the primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasOne(vehicle => vehicle.Driver)
            .WithOne(driver => driver.Vehicle)
            .HasForeignKey<Driver>(fk => fk.SSN)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Vehicle>(fk => new { fk.ChassisNr, fk.LicensePlate});
```

I have a class `Vehicle` with a `chassisnumber` and `licenseplate` combined as PK.

And there's also a `Driver` class with `SSN` as primary key.

Now when I try to add this migration, I get this message:

> The number of properties specified for the foreign key {'SSN'} on entity type 'Driver' does not match the number of properties in the principal key {'ChassisNr', 'LicensePlate'} on entity type 'Vehicle'

Is it even possible to achieve what I'm doing?

I need a 0/1 to 0/1 relation between these 2 models.

Comment: I assume you have this somewhere?  modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasKey(v => new { v.ChassisNr, v.LicensePlate });

Comment: yes i do.
aswell as this modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasKey(d => d.SSN);

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a foreign key on the dependent entity that matches the primary key of the principal entity.  Which entity you want to be principal and dependent is up to you.  For a principal `Driver` and dependent `Vehicle`, you would add `SSN` to `Vehicle`.  For the setup you have in your question where `Vehicle` is the principal, you would need to add the two properties that make up `Vehicle`’s PK to `Driver` and then create an anonymous object when defining the FK:

```
.HasForeignKey<Driver>( d => new 
{ 
    d.ChassisNr, 
    d.LicensePlate
} );
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one